# Using Azure Data Factory to migrate Salesforce data to Dynamics 365

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I'm looking for some advice around using Azure Data Factory to migrate data from Salesforce to Dynamics365.
My research has discovered plenty of articles about moving salesforce data to sinks such as azure data lakes or blob storage and also articles that describe moving data from azure data lakes or blob storage into D365.

I haven't found any examples where the source is salesforce and the sink is D365.

Is it possible to do it this way or do I need to copy the SF data to an intermediate sink such as Azure Data Lake or blob storage and then use that as the source of a copy/dataflow to then send to D365?

I will need to perform transformations on the SF data before storing it in D365.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add ADLS Gen 2 as a Stage between SalesForce and D365

[image]

I am afraid that a direct sink as D365 can be done